# Reverse Engineering (Generating) Tables or Database Schema from Models and Views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-2

***Update: The Question is Still Open, any reviews, comments are always welcome***

I am having an **existing rails project** in which some important files and directories has been **missed**.

project rails version (2.3.8) i found it in environment.rb

currently what i am having is

```
app
   controllers (already fully coded)
   helpers  (already fully coded)
   models (already fully coded) 
   reports (already fully coded)
   views  (already fully coded)

config ---> default configurations (already fully coded)
lib ---> contains nothing
public --> contains images and scripts (already fully coded)
script ---> contains server,runner,plugin,dbconsole....
```

app directory fully contains working state of codes, app/model contains more than 100 .rb files , so i assume it will be more than 100 tables

the mainly missing things are ***db directory, .gem file, rake file, doc, test, vendor, database,schema.rb and migrations***

**Note:**
  i don't  have the table schema and database for that project

**i am in Need to generate tables or complete database from models and views and 
i am looking for reverse engineering kind of stuff for generating db schema from models or views**

I am newbie to rails and i am from java background , in java by using hibernate there is an pojo(model in rails) to database option available, i am looking  for similar kind of stuffs for rails , and my main aim to run that project , so guys please help me.

Comment: Do you have migrations or schema.rb ? If you don't have any thing from this two then It is really hard to identify the schema of tables on the basis on models.

Comment: What bad luck, to be missing database, schema, and migrations - too bad you didn't lose script and retain one of those. I have to admit that I'm curious how something like this comes about, I bet it makes for an interesting story...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To recreate the database schema, it will take quite a bit of time.

You can get a lot of information about the database in the app/models, app/controllers app/views directory.

You should know that ActiveRecord **does not** require you to explicitly list all the attributes of a model. This has important implications - you can only **infer** what attributes you still have to add to the database, based on whether an attribute is referred to! This means doing this will be a bit of an ART. And there are no CLEAR steps to complete this work. But below are some rules which you can use to HELP you.

**This is a BIG project, below are guidelines, rules and tips to help you**. But be aware that this could take a **long** time, and be **frustrating** at times to get this done.

---

### What Tables you need:

Each table will normally have a matching **ActiveRecord::Base** model. So in the app/models directory, check each file, and if the class inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, it is an extra table.

The table name is by default a pluralized snake case version of the name of the class.

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base # for this class
```

the name of the table is user_groups. Notice it is plural, and instead of camel case, it is lowercase, with underscores to separate the words.

All these tables will have an "id" integer column. By default, the tables also have a "created_at", and "updated_at" column of type datetime.

### Associations and foreign keys:

You can infer what foreign keys exist by the associations in the Models. All associations are explicitly listed, so this is not too hard.

For example:

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base # for this class
  belongs_to :category
```

This means that the user_groups table has a column named "category_id", which is a foreign key for the categories table.

This means that the Category model likely has an inverse relationship (but no extra column):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
```

The main other association is the has_many_and_belongs_to association. Eg.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bs
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :as
end
```

This means that there is a join table to add called "as_bs" (as and bs are sorted alphabetically), with the foreign keys "a_id" and "b_id".

All foreign keys are integers.

---

### Attributes

Ok, so that's the table associations. Now for the normal attributes...

You should check the **app/views/user_groups/** or other similar **app/views** directories.

Inside you will find the view templates. You should look at the _form.html.erb templates (assuming it is .erb templates, otherwise it could be .haml etc templates).

The _form.html.erb template, if it exists, will normally have many of the attributes listed as form fields.

In the `form_for` block, check if it says something like `f.text_field :name`, it means there is an attribute/(column in the table) called "name". You can infer what type the column should be by what type of field it is. Eg. in this case, it is a string, so maybe a VARCHAR(255) is appropriate (referred to as string in Rails).

You might also need to infer what type is appropriate based on the name of the attribute (eg. if it mentions something like :time, then it is probably either of type Time or DateTime).

This may give you all the other attributes in the table. But in some cases, you might miss the attributes. If you find a reference to other attributes in the controller, eg. app/controllers/user_groups_controller.rb, then you should add that as a column in your table. You can leave this until the end when you test it though, because when you test it, if an attribute is missing, then it will throw a NoMethodError for the object of the relevant model. Eg. if it says that @user_group variable, of class UserGroup, is missing a method named title, then it probably is missing a column named "title" of type string.

---

### Recreate your migration/database

Ok, so now you know what the database tables and column names and types should be.

You should generate/recreate a migration for your database.

To do this, just use the command `rails generate migration RecreateTables`.

Then you should find a file in `db/migrate/???_recreate_tables.rb`.

Inside, start writing ruby code to create your tables. Reference for this can be found at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html.

But essentially, you will have something like:

```
class RecreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :user_groups do |t|
      t.string :name # adds a string (VARCHAR) column called "name"
      t.text :description # adds a textarea type column called "description
      t.timestamps # adds both "created_at" and "updated_at" columns for you
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :products # this is the reverse commands to undo stuff in "up"
  end
end
```

---

### To recreate your Gemfile:

Start by adding a default Gemfile. This can be done by using `rails new testapplication` somewhere to create an empty rails application. Then copy the Gemfile to your actual application. It will get you started by including rails and other common gems.

It is VERY hard to work out exactly what gems are needed. The best you can do is try adding them one by one as you look through the code.

Again, here, MethodNotFound errors are your FRIEND. When you test the application, based on the gems you have added, it might detect some missing methods which might be supplied by gems. Some missing methods on models might indicate missing gems (or they might indicate missing fields/columns in the database). However, missing methods on Controller or ActiveRelation classes are VERY likely because of missing gems.

You will have to look through the code and try to infer what gems to add.

If it uses methods like `can`, `can?`, and has a file `app/models/ability.rb`, then you need `gem 'cancan'`. If it calls `devise` in a model, it needs `gem 'devise'`. Many common gems can be seen at http://ruby-toolbox.com.

After adding gems to your Gemfile, you should run `bundle` on your command line to install the new gems before testing again. When you test it again, you should restart your test server. Rerun `bundle exec rails server` to start a local test server on `localhost:3000` or something like that.

You can simply copy the Rakefile from `rails new testapp`, and it will **probably** include everything you need.

### Missing Tests

The missing test/ directory is not relevant to your actual application. It is not required to run the application. However, it does hold automatic scripts to test your application. You will have to re-write new tests if you want to automatically test your application. However for the purpose of getting your application back up, you can ignore it for now.

### Missing vendor directory

Some extra code is not installed as a gem, but as a plugin. Anything installed as a plugin is lost if you don't have the vendor directory. As with gems, the best you can do is try to infer what might be missing, and re-download the missing plugin, either re-installing the plugin, or using a gem replacement.

---

### Additional tips:

- Try reading some of the comments which might name some of the gems used.
- If a method or set of methods are missing, that you think are not database fields/columns, it might be due to a missing gem. The best thing to do is to search google for those method names. Eg. if it is missing "paginate", you can search "rails paginate gem", and see what likely gems you might need. This example will probably come up with "will_paginate", and "kaminari". Then you have to try and infer which of the gems are required. Maybe do a `grep will_paginate app -r` on the command line to see if it is using will paginate. **The grep command searches for the string "will_paginate", in the directory called "app", -r makes it do this recursively for all files**

Answer (score 2):

Even though rails is a full stack  web framework it would work with out some parts as well, if you wish to,

Ex: in your case

**db** - directory is there for keep the migrations to create you DB/tables, but if you are using a legacy DB or the database stuff is handled by DB administrators, you might not want it. (you can simply connect to the DB via database.yml file)

Gem file is helping you to keep all the gems (libraries) in one place as you do with Maven (in java)

**test**, again if you done write test cases (which is absolutely a bad idea), you done need this

**vendor**, is for 3rd party plugins and doc is for documentation, so same rule applies, if you done need them you can skip them

Hibernate in rails called "Activerecord", same concept, a model is bind with a database table (technically model represents a raw in the table)

So if you really want them add them but if not just leave them

BUT, I think having a proper Gem file and test cases is a must

welcome come to Rails

HTH

Answer (score 2):

In the following, I assume you already know how to:

- dump your database schema into an SQL file
- start a Rails console (`rails c`)
- generate a Rails migration

Here's what I think you should do.

1. Identify which of your classes correspond to physical tables (you mention some views in your question, which leads me to believe a subset of your models are bound to database views instead of actual tables). To do this you need to match the definitions of your models (classes which extend ActiveRecord::Base) to `CREATE TABLE` statements in your schema dump. For instance, `class Person` in your Ruby code matches to `CREATE TABLE people` in your DB schema dump.
2. Once you identified those models (class names), you start up a Rails console and you type those model names, one at a time, and press Enter. The console output for a model called Person would presumably look like this:

`>> Person`
`=> Person(id: integer, first_name: string, last_name: string)`

You then take what's inside the parentheses, strip the leading `id: integer,`, get rid of commas, get rid of those blanks after the colons, thus obtaining something like this:

`first_name:string last_name:string`

Having done this, the command to generate the migration would look like this:

`rails g migration Person first_name:string last_name:string`

You then start a new Rails project somewhere else, perform all of these migrations and inspect the contents of `db/migrate`. Your migrations are most likely 90% done, what you still need to do is replace some instances of `t.integer` with `t.references`, and other minor stuff that's completely domain-specific and impossible to capture in a generic answer.

HTH.

Comment: Your answer has a big problem! You can't use the Rails console to check the attributes in a model if the database is not up. ActiveRecord uses the database table to infer what attributes are in the model. That is why you do not have to declare each attribute in the class.